# Jest mock return value of inner function of exported var

Tags: jestjs, mocking, vue-test-utils

`report.api.js`:

```
export var reportAPI = (function() {

  function getIsProjectLeader() {
     ....
  }

  return {
      getIsProjectLeader: getIsProjectLeader
  };
}
```

`workerReportForm.vue`:

```
created() {
    reportAPI.getIsProjectLeader().then((result) => {
```

`xyz.spec.js`:

```
import { reportAPI } from "@/api/report.api.js";
jest.mock('@/api/report.api.js')

describe("<worker-report-form>", () => {
  it("should render the form", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(WorkerReportForm, {
      global: {},
      propsData: {},
      components: {},
    });

    expect(reportAPI.getIsProjectLeader).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I get:

```
● <worker-report-form> › should render the form

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

    > 210 |     reportAPI.getIsProjectLeader().then((result) => {
          |                                   ^
```

So how can I mock the return value of `getIsProjectLeader`() ?

Comment: You can't. It's not a property of the outer function, it's defined inside it.

Comment: I have added the lines at the end of my `report.api.js`. does it make a difference now?

Comment: Yes, it's accessible at least. But it's not clear why you expected different behaviour - your test double, which is just the default Jest provides, doesn't return _anything_, let alone a promise with a then method.

Comment: What would you recommend as solution?

Comment: Like any test double, your mock of getIsProjectLeader needs to **at least** match the API of the thing it's replacing. The Jest docs show you how to configure mock functions' return values, there are several options when that value is a promise: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api

Comment: I tried with `const spy = jest.spyOn(reportAPI, 'getIsProjectLeader');
    spy.mockResolvedValue(Promise....);` but it didnt work

Comment: So _show that_, what exactly does "didn't work" mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251739/discussion-between-farahm-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Well, I still get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`
` > 210 | reportAPI.getIsProjectLeader().then((result) => {
|                                                                    ^`